# DllRegisterServer error 0xc0000005, (C++ COM Dll). how do I debug my DllRegisterServer function in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, com, dll, dllregistration

I have written a COM dll, and wish to register it using

```
regsvr32 myComdll.dll
```

I get an error :

```
DllRegisterServer failed, Return code was: 0xc0000005
```

I want to debug my DllRegsiterServer function, but I do not know how to set up Visual Studio 2008 to run regsvr32 in debug mode...

Thanks

Roey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project + Properties, Debugging, set Command = Regsvr32.exe $(TargetPath).  Set a breakpoint on your DllRegisterServer function or use Debug + Exceptions, check Win32 Exceptions.  Press F5 to get it going.

Answer (score 3):

1 set regsvr32 as you exe to start

2 Set the arguments in visual studio to be the path to your debug dll

3 set a breakpoint in the register function.

4 Start Debugging

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but there's always old reliable `Sleep()` - you insert `Sleep()` call as the first statement of the function of interest (`DllRegisterServer()` in your case) and recompile the project. Then you set a breakpoint into the next statement, run regsvr32 and attach the debugger to it. regsvr32 calls the function and after `Sleep()` returns execution is stopped on the next statement.

Nothing to setup, but requires recompliling.